# Best way to distinguish syntactically identical but sematically different types?

Tags: c++, types, eigen

I am using C++ and the Eigen library for a ray-tracer project. I need to distinguish position vectors, which participate in any arbitrary transformation, including translation, and direction vectors, which only participate in rotation and scaling. Other than this one operation, the vectors are identical, and both are derived from the `Eigen::Vector3d` class.

> The math is easy -- transformations are encoded as 4x4 matrices. A 3-element *position* vector is stretched to 4 elements, with the last element w being hard-coded to 1. Then when it is multiplied by a matrix which includes translation, the w=1 forces the translation to happen. A 3-element *direction* vector is similarly stretched to 4 elements, but the new element is hard-coded to 0. Then when *it* is multiplied, the 0 forces the translation to *not* happen. In effect, translation in 3D is treated as skewing in 4D, and the w coordinate determines the vector position in 4D, and whether it is on the w=1 plane which is skewed, or the w=0 plane which is not. In both cases, after the matrix multiplication, the last element is dropped to turn the vector back into 3D.

The obvious-but-wrong solution is:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

//stretch a 3D vector to 4D by appending a new element
inline Eigen::Vector4d extend(const Eigen::Vector3d& v, double w) {
  Eigen::Vector4d result;
  result<<v,w;
  return result;
}

//Reverse of extend()
inline Eigen::Vector3d deextend(const Eigen::Vector4d& v) {
  return v.head<3>();
}

typedef Eigen::Vector3d PositionVector;
typedef Eigen::Vector3d DirectionVector;

inline PositionVector operator*(const Eigen::Matrix4d& M, PositionVector v) {
  return deextend(M*extend(v,1));
}

inline DirectionVector operator*(const Eigen::Matrix4d& M, DirectionVector v) {
  return deextend(M*extend(v,0));
}
```

but this doesn't work because `PositionVector` and `DirectionVector` aren't really different types, so the compiler can't distinguish them.

My next idea, which partially works, is to have both object extend `Eigen::Vector3D` directly:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

inline Eigen::Vector4d extend(...) {/* same as above */}
inline Eigen::Vector3d deextend(...) {/* same as above */}

class PositionVector:public Eigen::Vector3d {};
class DirectionVector:public Eigen::Vector3d {};

inline PositionVector operator*(...) {/*same as above*/}
inline DirectionVector operator*(...) {/*same as above*/}
```

I say it partially works, because while this code as-is works, I had to add a bunch of `static_cast<>`s and delegating constructors to the rest of the code. I did too good of a job at distinguishing the types, and now the compiler isn't always smart enough to convert between the Eigen vectors and my vectors, without some hints.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

inline Eigen::Vector4d extend(...) {/* same as above */}
inline Eigen::Vector3d deextend(...) {/* same as above */}

class PositionVector:public Eigen::Vector3d {
 /* This is a subset of the literally dozens of potential constructors I might have to make.
    They are the only ones my code has used so far, but who knows about the future? */
  PositionVector() {}
  PositionVector(Eigen::Vector3d matrix): Eigen::Vector3d(matrix) {}
  PositionVector(double x, double y, double z):Eigen::Vector3d(x,y,z) {}
};
class DirectionVector:public Eigen::Vector3d {
/* Exact same constructors, except with DirectionVector() instead of PositionVector(). I wish
   you could just inherit constructors, but in C++ you can't. */
  DirectionVector() {}
  DirectionVector(Eigen::Vector3d matrix): Eigen::Vector3d(matrix) {}
  DirectionVector(double x, double y, double z):Eigen::Vector3d(x,y,z) {}
};

inline PositionVector operator*(...) {/*same as above*/}
inline DirectionVector operator*(...) {/*same as above*/}

/* An example of code which uses these classes */
class Ray {
  //...other stuff
  PositionVector r0;
  DirectionVector v0;
  PositionVector operator()(double t) {
    /* Ugly static cast. How many more will I need? */
    return static_cast<Eigen::Vector3d>(r0+v*t);
  }
  Ray &operator*=(const Eigen::Matrix4d &M) {
    r0 = M*r0;
    v = M*v;
    return *this;
  }
};

inline Ray operator*(const Eigen::Matrix4d &M, Ray ray) {
  ray *= M;
  return ray;
}

Eigen::Matrix4d M=/*...*/;
Ray ray1=/*...*/;
Ray ray2=M*ray1;
PositionVector r=ray2(42.0);
```

One improvement I could see is that since `PositionVector` and `DirectionVector` are almost identical, I can template them:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

inline Eigen::Vector4d extend(...) {/* same as above */}
inline Eigen::Vector3d deextend(...) {/* same as above */}

template<int W>
class PDVector:public Eigen::Vector3d {
 /* Still needs potentially many more constructors, but now only in one place */
  PDVector() {}
  PDVector(Eigen::Vector3d matrix): Eigen::Vector3d(matrix) {}
  PDVector(double x, double y, double z):Eigen::Vector3d(x,y,z) {}
};
typedef PDVector<1> PositionVector;
typedef PDVector<0> DirectionVector;

template<int W>
inline PDVector<W> operator*(const Eigen::Matrix4d& M, PDVector<W> v) {
  return deextend(M*extend(v,W));
}
```

I understand *why* the compiler needs this ugliness. I'm not complaining about the language. But, it seems like I'm fighting the language, which is usually a sign that there is probably a much more elegant way to do all of this, and that I just don't know enough about the language. If I really do need all this ugliness, I'm ready to hide it deep inside the library, but how do I keep the calling interface nice and clean? How do I keep this ugliness from leaking out? Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: If all you really want to do is give the types better names, you can use a alias like `using PositionVector = Eigen::Vector3d; using DirectionVector = Eigen::Vector3d;`  This doesn't give you type safety, but it does give you better naming.

Comment: C++ *does* have constructor inheritance! A `using Eigen::Vector3d::Vector3d;` declaration in your classes will inherit the constructors... except the copy constructor is also inherited but keeps its parameter type (`Vector3d const&`; it stops being a copy constructor), so the two different types will just convert into each other implicitly via it. I'm actually wondering if you can just add a better, `delete`d overload for that case...